# Split a field having mutiple values separated by comma into multiple records in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with 3 fields. All are varchar(256).

For example:

```
Name :               Id:               Comment:
Charles        ["92736","387625"]       hello
```

I want a output like this:

```
Name :               Id:               Comment:
Charles             92736                hello
Charles             387625               hello
```

The code that I run is:

```
SELECT name, STRTOK(id, ',', i) AS x, comment
FROM test
CROSS JOIN
 ( 
   SELECT day_of_calendar AS i
   FROM sys_calendar.CALENDAR
   WHERE i <= 15
 ) AS dt
WHERE x IS NOT NULL;
```

The output that I get is:

```
Name :               Id:                  Comment:
Charles             ["92736"                hello
Charles             "387625"]               hello
```

I donot want the [ and " characters in my output. I just want the numeric values as a number.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Tip of today: Never, ever store data as comma separated items! It will only cause you lots of trouble!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Teradata? (The answer will probably be product specific.)

Comment: Hi, i am using teradata. And the values are stored as VARCHAR(256) but in the form of an array. For example : ["38263","237463","64244"]

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional split-characters:

```
STRTOK(id, ',["]', i)
```

Another solution is to avoid the Cross-Join and switch to `STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE` instead:

```
WITH cte AS 
 (
   SELECT Name AS inKey,
          id AS inString,
          comment
   FROM test
 ) 
SELECT * FROM 
 (
   SELECT * 
   FROM TABLE (STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(cte.inKey
                                    ,cte.inString
                                    ,',["]') 
   RETURNS (outKey VARCHAR(40) 
           ,TokenNum INT 
           ,Token VARCHAR(20)) AS dt
 ) AS dt
JOIN cte
ON cte.inKey = dt.outKey
```

Comment: Hi, any reason with STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE is better than the earlier approach?

Comment: @Austin: No, it's just a variation, you might test which is more efficent.